# Standalone merging / 3-way equivalent of git diff --no-index

Tags: git, command-line, diff, three-way-merge

We can use `git`'s diff tool without git repos with `git diff --no-index <FILE-A> <FILE-B>`.

Is there a similar command for running `git`'s merge algorithm given three input files ("ours", base & "theirs")? And specifically it should output the "diff3" style (seeing the "base" in the conflict is essential)

I understand that it couldn't be as smart as git's recursive merge strategy but I would be very satisfied with something basic like the "resolve" strategy.

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/merge

Comment: @phd I didn't find a quick way to install this on my macOS setup, but reading the docs it appears that it's not in git's diff3 style (which indeed I didn't explcitly ask for in my question - I'll correct it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
git merge-file -p --diff3 ours base theirs
```

Comment: Thanks! I've accepted and edited the answer to add the `-p` parameter to output the result on standard output (otherwise it isn't clear where it goes)

Comment: @yairchu: without `-p`, `git merge-file` writes the result back to the first named file (`ours` here).

Answer (score 1):

> running git's merge algorithm

There are actually more than one merge result, depending on the diff algorithm used: myers, minimal, patience, and histogram.
See "[When to Use Each of the Git Diff Algorithms](https://luppeng.wordpress.com/2020/10/10/when-to-use-each-of-the-git-diff-algorithms/)" by [Lup Peng Loke](https://www.linkedin.com/in/lup-peng-loke), for details on those.

As mentioned in [jthill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1290731/jthill)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64540272/6309), you can use [`git merge-file`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-file):

```
git merge-file -p --diff3 ours base theirs
```

With Git 2.44 (Q1 2024), "[`git merge-file`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/78956864b095fb8f9336c46c2573d28cd6ee601e/Documentation/git-merge-file.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt-file))</sup> learned to take the `--diff-algorithm` option to use an algorithm different from the default myers diff.

See [commit 4f7fd79](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4f7fd79e57f483282bc21bf5b0669f9c8229d32a) (20 Nov 2023) by [Antonin Delpeuch (`wetneb`)](https://github.com/wetneb).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7895686](https://github.com/git/git/commit/78956864b095fb8f9336c46c2573d28cd6ee601e), 18 Dec 2023)</sup>

> ### [`merge-file`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4f7fd79e57f483282bc21bf5b0669f9c8229d32a): add --diff-algorithm option
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Antonin Delpeuch</sup>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Phillip Wood</sup>

> Make it possible to use other diff algorithms than the 'myers' default algorithm, when using the '[`git merge-file`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4f7fd79e57f483282bc21bf5b0669f9c8229d32a/Documentation/git-merge-file.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt-file))</sup> command, to help avoid spurious conflicts by selecting a more recent algorithm such as 'histogram', for instance when using '`git merge-file`' as part of a custom merge driver.

`git merge-file` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4f7fd79e57f483282bc21bf5b0669f9c8229d32a/Documentation/git-merge-file.txt#L95-L100):

> ### `--diff-algorithm={patience|minimal|histogram|myers}`
>
> Use a different diff algorithm while merging.
>
> The current default is "myers", but selecting more recent algorithm such as "histogram" can help avoid mismerges that occur due to unimportant matching lines (such as braces from distinct functions).
>
> See also
> [`git diff --diff-algorithm`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---diff-algorithmpatienceminimalhistogrammyers).

So now:

```
git merge-file -p --diff-algorithm={patience|minimal|histogram|myers} --diff3 ours base theirs
```

---

"[`git diff --no-index file1 file2`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/92e69dfb66fa5c760e2d1f76c8a21cdb6faacaee/Documentation/git-diff.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff))</sup> segfaulted while invoking the external diff driver, which has been corrected with Git 2.44 (Q1 2024), [batch 14](https://github.com/git/git/commit/235986be822c9f8689be2e9a0b7804d0b1b6d821).

See [commit 85a9a63](https://github.com/git/git/commit/85a9a63c9268b18b24f25f6a14d6ae9966c3566d) (28 Jan 2024) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 92e69df](https://github.com/git/git/commit/92e69dfb66fa5c760e2d1f76c8a21cdb6faacaee), 06 Feb 2024)</sup>

> ### [`diff`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/85a9a63c9268b18b24f25f6a14d6ae9966c3566d): handle NULL meta-info when spawning external diff
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Wilfred Hughes</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> Running this:
>
> ```
> $ touch foo bar
> $ chmod +x foo
> $ git -c diff.external=echo diff --ext-diff --no-index foo bar
> ```
>
> results in a segfault.
>
> The issue is that `run_diff_cmd()` passes a `NULL` `"xfrm_msg"` variable to `run_external_diff()`, which feeds it to `strvec_push()`, causing the segfault.
>
> The bug dates back to [82fbf26](https://github.com/git/git/commit/82fbf269b9994d172719b2d456db5ef8453b323d) (`run_external_diff`: use an argv_array for the command line, 2014-04-19, Git v2.0.0-rc2 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5f11a7aad0704918fde4855500caba6a3f130648)) `(run_external_diff`: use an `argv_array` for the command line, 2014-04-19), though it mostly only ever worked accidentally.
> Before then, we just stuck the `NULL` pointer into a "const char **" array, so our `NULL` ended up acting as an extra end-of-argv sentinel (which was OK, because it was the last thing in the array).
>
> Curiously, though, this is only a problem with `--no-index`.
> We set up `xfrm_msg` by calling `fill_metainfo()`.
> This result may be empty, or may have text like "index 1234..5678\n", "rename from foo\nrename from bar\n", etc.
> In `run_external_diff()`, we only look at `xfrm_msg` if the "other" variable is not `NULL`.
> That variable is set when the paths of the two sides of the diff pair aren't the same (in which case the destination path becomes "other").
> So normally it would kick in only for a rename, in which case `xfrm_msg` should not be `NULL` (it would have the rename information in it).
>
> But with a "`--no-index`" of two blobs, we of course have two different pathnames, and thus end up with a non-NULL "other" filename (which is always just a repeat of the file2-name), but possibly a `NULL xfrm_msg`.
>
> So how to fix it? I have a feeling that `--no-index` always passing other to the external diff command is probably a bug.
> There was no rename, and the name is always redundant with existing information we pass (and this may even cause us to pass a useless `"xfrm_msg"` that contains an "`index 1234..5678`" line).
> So one option would be to change that behavior.
> We don't seem to have ever documented the "other" or `"xfrm_msg"` parameters for external diffs.
>
> But I'm not sure what fallout we might have from changing that behavior now.
> So this patch takes the less-risky option, and simply teaches `run_external_diff()` to avoid passing `xfrm_msg` when it's `NULL`.
> That makes it agnostic to whether "other" and `"xfrm_msg"` always come as a pair.
> It fixes the segfault now, and if we want to change the `--no-index` other behavior on top, it will handle that, too.